# Show latest blog posts on custom page template

Tags: php, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I need some help converting this code from SS3 to SS4.
I used the code below to pull my latest blog posts through to my custom homepage template. This no longer works for me in SS4. Not sure how what needs to be added to fix it.

```
class IndexPageController extends PageController {
public function LatestPostsHome()
    {
        return BlogCategory::get()
        ->filter('Title', 'Featured')
        ->relation('BlogPosts')
        ->sort('PublishDate', 'DESC');
    }
}
```

Thank,

Answer (score 1):

Do you have several BlogCategories with the same title?

If you only have one BlogCategory with title 'Featured' then this should work:

```
public function LatestPostsHome()
    {
        $blogCategory = BlogCategory::get()->filter('Title', 'Featured')->first();
        if (!$blogCategory) {
            return null;
        }
        // Get the corresponding has_many/many_many objects.
        $blogPosts = $blogCategory->BlogPosts()->sort('PublishDate', 'DESC');

        return $blogPosts;
    }
```

If you have multiple categories with the same title, then you can maybe use something like this:

```
public function LatestPostsHome()
{
    $blogCategories = BlogCategory::get()->filter('Title', 'Featured');

    if (!$blogCategories->exists()) {
        return null;
    }

    // Option 1 (not tested)
    $categoryIDs = $blogCategories->column('ID');
    $blogPosts = BlogPost::get()->byIDs($categoryIDs);

    return $blogPosts;


    // Option 2 (not tested)
    $blogPosts = new \SilverStripe\ORM\ArrayList();
    foreach ($blogCategories as $category) {
        $posts = $category->BlogPosts();
        $blogPosts->push($posts->toNestedArray());
    }

    return $blogPosts;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This was a great help. I noticed an error message which was similar to another question I had so I tweaked it slightly and it solved the error message and pulled the blog through to the homepage. This is the revised code if anyone else would like to give it a try too:

*****  $blogCategory = \silverstripe\blog\Model\BlogCategory::get()->filter('Title', 'Walkies')->first();
        

Thank you again.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I could help!